# Rails controller dynamic update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, controller

So I want to make a rails website and I want to display people.

I have various scopes for active people, by team, by gender and such like this:

```ruby
scope :alphabetical, order('last_name, first_name')

scope :active, where('active = ?', true)

scope :inactive, where('active =?', false)

scope :female, where('female = ?', true)

scope :male, where('female = ?', false)

scope :for_school, lambda {|id| where("school_id = ?", id)}
```

but in displaying all these people on the website, I want to have multiple dropdowns where multiple scopes are called. Like I could go back and forth between active and inactive but also back and forth between male and female.

So I would start with People.active at first but when male is selected, I want to change it to People.male.active. Then if another dropdown is selected for school, then I want to do `People.male.active.for_school(x)`.

I am farely new to rails so I don't know how to dynamically change requests on controller. I assume I have to write a method but the method looked VERY hard-codey. Is there a gem that simplifies my task? Or how should I go about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) may be what you are after.

See [ransack demo](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/).